# Problem installing on MediaTemple

Tags: installation

I'm getting an error when I start the installation process, i.e., `<domain>/admin`.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected. The SQL statement executed was: SHOW TABLES LIKE 'craft_%'
```

Since I've enabled dev mode, you can see the full stack trace here:

http://onehanders.info/admin

I've done the following prior to starting the install:

- set up db and identified server, db name, user, & password that are needed
- put proper settings in db.php in the config folder
- put the craft folder one level above web root
- updated all 3 of the relevant folder permissions (including enclosed)
- enabled dev mode in `general.php`

I even added a statement to `craft/etc/behaviors/AppBehaviors.php`. After line 852, at which point the db connection appears to be valid, I echo'd a "db connection is valid" line and got there. That line is now commented out.

I'd love to hear your thoughts on what I might try to fix this.

Contents of `config/db.php`:

```
<?php

/**
* Database Configuration
*
* All of your system's database configuration settings go in here.
* You can see a list of the default settings in craft/app/etc/config/defaults/db.php
*/

return array(

// The database server name or IP address. Usually this is 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.
'server' => 'internal-db.s<my acct #>.gridserver.com',

// The name of the database to select.
'd<my acct #>_onehanders_db' => '',

// The database username to connect with.
'user' => 'db<my acct #>',

// The database password to connect with.
'password' => '<my password>',

// The prefix to use when naming tables. This can be no more than 5 characters.
'tablePrefix' => 'craft',

);
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try this fix: https://craftcms.com/support/forms-returning-json

Comment: Thanks for the try Brad, but I've already done that.

Comment: Can you share the contents of your `craft/config/db.php` file (with the sensitive bits redacted)?

Comment: Sure. I'll edit the post to include it.

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
// The name of the database to select.
'd<my acct #>_onehanders_db' => '',
```

Needs to be this:

```
// The name of the database to select.
'database' => 'd<my acct #>_onehanders_db',
```

Comment: Thanks Brad. That was a rather egregious error. My apologies.

Comment: I forgot to say, explicitly...that worked! My installation was successful. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, @BobMonsour. And bonus points for using the word "egregious". :)